# Iterate over rows in R

Tags: r, python-3.x

Can you please convert this python code into R-code? Thank you so much.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'A':10, 'B':100}, {'A':11,'B':110}, {'A':12,'B':120}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A'] == 10:
        print(row['B'])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: in R just do `df$B[df$A==10]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `list` of data then `rbind` it into the `data.frame`. After it you can use subsetting. Please see the code below:

```
data <- list(c(a = 10, b = 100), c(a = 11,  b = 110), c(a = 12, b = 120))
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, data))
df[df$a == 10, ]$b
```

Output:

```
[1] 100
```

Or you can emulate Python's approach with `for` loop, however not as efficient and elegant as above one:

```
data <- list(c(a = 10, b = 100), c(a = 11,  b = 110), c(a = 12, b = 120))
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, data))
for (index in seq.int(nrow(df)))
  if (df[index, "a"] == 10)
    print(df[index, "b"])
```

Output is the same:

```
[1] 100
```